# unexpected T_CATCH, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, error-handling

Today, while trying to write this User class, I ran into the above error on the highlighted line below, and was wondering what you lot thought of it.

```
class User {
  public $username;
  public $password;
  public $user_info;
  public $connection;

  function __construct($username) {
   $connection = new Database();
   try {
   $user_info = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
   if ($user_info == null) {
    throw new Exception("Could not find user details, please try again later!");
   }
   ***} catch (Exception $login) {***
    die($login->getMessage());
   }
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["dgs_tech"] = $user_info;
  }

  function update_info() {
   $user_info = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
   if ($user_info == null) {
    throw new Exception("Could not find user details, please try again later!");
   }
   } catch (Exception $login) {
    die($login->getMessage());
   }
   $_SESSION{"dgs_tech"] = $user_info;
  }

  function return_info() {
   $text = "<p>"
   foreach($user_info as $name => $item) {
    $text += "<h1>$name:</h1>$item<br/>";
   }
   $text += "</p>";
   return $text;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is about to function update_info()
You do not have "try{" there

Comment: Unfortunately, pretty much as soon as I posted this, I noticed the lack of "try {". There were several other errors which I fixed, but thanks very much anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code: Try it now:

```
class User
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $user_info;
    public $connection;

    function __construct($username)
    {
        $connection = new Database();
        try
        {
            $user_info = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
            if ($user_info == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not find user details, please try again later!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $login)
        {
            die($login->getMessage());
        }
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["dgs_tech"] = $user_info;
    }

    function update_info()
    {
        try
        {
            $user_info = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
            if ($user_info == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not find user details, please try again later!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $login)
        {
            die($login->getMessage());
        }
        $_SESSION["dgs_tech"] = $user_info;
    }

    function return_info()
    {
        $text = "<p>"
        foreach($user_info as $name => $item)
        {
            $text += "<h1>$name:</h1>$item<br/>";
        }
        $text += "</p>";
        return $text;
    }
}
```

It had the problem where Try started from one function and ending on another.

And you should **correctly indent** your code. The bugs will become clear *automagically*.

Comment: Why You're doing this thing for him? :P We should post answers for questions witch will allow to find and fix, not ready-to-go "I did it for You" ;)

Comment: @Dariusz, He can not correct it himself, that's why he asked it here. I think we can help our fellow coders by being clear and elaborate.

Comment: Yep, but that way only teach method: "I can't do it, let others do it for me", and pointing where-to-find, forces user, to teach where he have made mistake... Do You want everyone only ask heare "fix it for me please?" ;)

Comment: @Dariusz, I corrected the code, along with specifying the reason and giving tip on correct indentation which will let him not repeat the mistake. What else do you want from me ?

Comment: @shamittomar I do not want anything, there is nothin' wrong in Yours answer, i just was only surprised, that You have pasted ready to go code instead of just (only) pointing out mistake :) not more not less

Comment: Sounds like Dariusz is worried that Shamittomar might win the "best answer"... problem is, this question is asked by a new person that will probably never get any response back. Hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your construct function accolades {} are not correctly closing and you have code outside a function.